# Error in dropdown menu when I click on Main option with children elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have the following code in html

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <a href="url1">URL1</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="url11">URL1_1</a></li>
    <li><a href="url12">URL1_2</a></li>
....
```

CSS code:

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

And JS code:

```
$(function() {

  $("ul > li > ul").addClass("hidden");
  $("ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
    var li = $(this).parent();      
    e.preventDefault();     
    li.find("ul").first().slideToggle();        
   });      
});
```

If use `e.preventDefault();` my submenu is shown but my `ul>li> a` is not redirected my page to a href link.

Then... if I delete `e.preventDefault();` then my submenu is shown, my page is redirected to the a href link but immediately my submenu is hidden again.
Can you help me please?

Comment: these type of menus usually open on hover (of the `li`) rather than onclick for this reason.  Also, you closed your `li` before you put the `ul` in it (guessing that's just a typo here though)

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding classes to the UL tags.

You problem here is that

```
 $("ul > li > a").click(function(e)
```

Will get stuck in a loop and block the click from the child ul.

I would try giving them classes like - first-level, second-level and use that in your jQuery selector.

```
 $(".second-level").addClass("hidden");
 $(".first-level > a").click(function(e) {
```

It's not good to use such general selectors on the raw element tags IMHO. hopefully this helps you